# Get CompletionBlock for CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I have not much experience in Objective-C.
I'm trying to get the end of the animation after the user has pressed a button.
In `viewDidLoad` I have added this:

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recoginzer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onPress:)];
 [_buttonStart addGestureRecognizer:recoginzer];
```

then in the method I used `setCompletionBlock` to determine when the animation is over, but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)onPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longpress {

if (longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(2, 2, _buttonStart.frame.size.width-4, _buttonStart.frame.size.height-4) cornerRadius:(_buttonStart.frame.size.width/2)-8].CGPath;
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    [_buttonStart.layer addSublayer:circle];


    [CATransaction begin];
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 3.0;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"DONE");
        }];

    [CATransaction commit];


} else if (longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || longpress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {

    [circle removeFromSuperlayer];
    NSLog(@"long press OUT");

}
}
```

thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `setCompletionBlock` before adding the animations.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/setCompletionBlock:) (emphasis mine):

> The completion block object that is guaranteed to be called (on the main thread) as soon as all animations **subsequently** added by this transaction group have completed (or have been removed.)

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"DONE");
}];

[circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thanks! For not calling the block in UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled and UIGestureRecognizerState Failed When the animation is not complete [circle removeFromSuperlayer]; how can I do?